# reset key after count reached

Tags: php, loops, foreach, array-key

So I am trying to grab just 4 keys at a time out of an array and then reset the key count back to 0 after the 4th one is reached (actually key #3, because the array starts with 0). Here's an example:

```
0 - USA Mix #1
1 - 24mg
2 - 252
3 - value
4 - USA Mix #1
5 - 24mg
6 - 252
7 - value
```

I have tried using unset($key['0']), unset($ket['1']), etc and that hasn't worked. I tried using array_shift and that doesn't seem to work. I'd like to reset the key pattern after 4 counts. The reason is, that on the 4th key looped, it is then supposed to do an insert grabbing the "block" (block contains 4 keys) - something like this:

```
foreach($temp_atts as $key=>$val){


            if($key == 0){
                $attribute_name = $val;
            }
            if($key == 1){
                $attribute_option = $val;
            }

          if($i <= 4){
               $sql_C = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE attribute_name = '{$attribute_name}' AND attribute_option = '{$attribute_option}' AND hc_cat = '{$_GET['cat_id']}' AND hc_s_cat = '{$_GET['sub_cat']}' AND hc_prod_id = '{$_GET['prod_id']}'";
               echo $sql_C . '<br>';


            $i = 0;
        }


        $i++;
    }
```

I'm having some difficulties getting it to reset the keys after the 4th count. Could someone offer a pointer as to what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?  Thanks

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would like to have a word with you!

Comment: This: `unset($key['1'])` wouldn't work as you're referencing a string, have you tried: `unset($key[1])` without the apostrophes (`'`) ?

Comment: yes, I have tried that as well. Each insert echoed still only shows USA Mix #1 and attribute_option of 24mg. It doesn't reset

Comment: @AmalMurali - code work - then code clean up ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion on how to better accomplish what (I think) you're trying to do.

Consider using [**array_chunk()**](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
// Your current array. Values in [4] and [5] changed slightly for clarity
$arr = array('USA Mix #1','24mg','252','value','USA Mix #2','240mg','252','value');

$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 4);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $sql_C = "
    SELECT * FROM attributes
    WHERE attribute_name = '{$chunk[0]}' 
        AND attribute_option = '{$chunk[1]}'
    ";
    echo $sql_C . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM attributes
WHERE attribute_name = 'USA Mix #1' 
    AND attribute_option = '24mg'


SELECT * FROM attributes
WHERE attribute_name = 'USA Mix #2' 
    AND attribute_option = '240mg'
```

Hopefully I am understanding your problem correctly, and this is helpful.

*Note that I left off a large part of your query because I cannot endorse doing such as thing as putting `$_GET` values directly into a query. @Amal Murali's comment should help to clarify why.

Comment: thanks for the help. That solved the problem. Yes I know the $_GET isn't the best approach. But for the moment, it's about getting the code working (which it now does), and then I will add the cleanQuery() function after. Thanks again!

Comment: @MrTechie No problem, glad to help. And, ya, I understand the "get it to work first" approach - I do that all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the $key as index and use $i all the way. That should work. Do not that in this example $sql_C will be overwritten for every 4th element. Also never change the array you're looping through, the result in most cases won't be the result you were expecting.

You could substitude the if block with a switch case for even fancier code.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($temp_atts as $val)
{

   if ($i == 0) {
       $attribute_name = $val;
   } elseif ($i == 1) {
       $attribute_option = $val;
   } elseif($i == 4) {
       // Sanitize input like mentioned in the comments
       $sql_C = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE attribute_name = '{$attribute_name}' AND attribute_option = '{$attribute_option}' AND hc_cat = '{$_GET['cat_id']}' AND hc_s_cat = '{$_GET['sub_cat']}' AND hc_prod_id = '{$_GET['prod_id']}'";
       echo $sql_C . '<br>';

       $i = 0;
   }


   ++$i;
}
```

Credits to [Amal Murai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438393/amal-murali) for mentioning our friend Little Bobby Tables.